# How to get out of outermost loop in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
  while true; do
    <do this>
    for a in 1 2 3 4 5; do
       <<do this>>
    done
        if [ "$someVar1" == "$someVar2" ]; then

            if [ -f "$numberOfFiles" ]; then
                if [ "$countValue1" == "$countValue2" ]; then
                    <<do this>>
                    break     
            else
        echo "in the else part"
       done
      done
```

While trying the above code I want to get completely out of the third `if` statement and for that I m using `break`. But the break statement is getting out of the `if` and going into the `else` part and iterating over and over again. How do I get out of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help break`:

> break: break [n]
> Exit for, while, or until loops.
>
> ```
> Exit a FOR, WHILE or UNTIL loop.  If N is specified, break N enclosing
> loops.
>
> Exit Status:
> The exit status is 0 unless N is not greater than or equal to 1.
> ```

`break` supports an optional argument: the number of enclosing loops to *break*.

In your example it would be

```
break 3
```